# Does the vector still exists?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm having a problem in my c++ game related with the vector.
I want to know if theres any code that tells me if a vector still exists.
Example (x = a structure that I created):

```
vector<x*> var;
var.push_back(new x);
var[5]->Pos_X = 10;
```

And now what i want:

```
delete var[5];

if(var[5] still exists){
     var[5]->Pos_X = 20;
}
```

What could be the code for **var[5] still exists**?

Comment: I can sense bad design here. Also: define "still exists".

Comment: Because the structure is used for the objects in the game.

Comment: You should be able to determine that via the scope of the object, shouldn't you?

Comment: In your example `var[5]` never did exist...

Comment: It's no explanation for storing pointers, @TiagoSalzmann. Again: try to redesign it, rather than finding a way to utilize bad design. Solve original problem, not problem that has arisen when you tried to solve it.

Comment: How? I don't want to create another vector or array to store a boolean (saying if the vector objects still exist)

Comment: If you delete var[5] and then try to access var[5] it will cause an access violation as it doesn't exist. You can call var.at(5) which will thrown an out of bounds exception which means you have to wrap in a try catch statement. If your example is that simple you can just test by checking the size of the vector by calling vector.size() and see if this matches the index you want to access (also remembering that indexes in vectors are zero-based).

Comment: Perhaps if you gave a broader view of what you're trying to accomplish, you might get help solving the root issue.

Comment: What's wrong with simply storing objects rather than pointers, and erase them from the vector?

Comment: @EdChum, no - accessing `delete`d variables is undefined behavior, as the address is probably still in process' address space and it still contain the same data (unless your implementation uses something like `cfree()` as analogy to `calloc()`). Also, calling `var.at(5)` isn't a solution, as the pointer will still be there and vector will not say it's out of it's bounds.

Comment: @Griwes thanks for the clarification, I missed the point that Tiago is deleting the pointer, Tiago-Salzman if you want to remove something from the vector then you should call vector.erase().

Comment: I wonder if a `std::map<size_t, x>` might be a better fit for his mysterious use case?

Comment: Your entire concept of "exists" is nonsensical here. `delete` doesn't delete the pointer, it deletes the pointed-at thing, leaving the pointer dangling (and still in the vector). There is **no way**, given just a pointer, to determine if it is valid; you are responsible for writing code that ensures that you only ever use valid pointers, by making sure you can prove to yourself, at compile-time, that it will only ever use valid pointers.

Comment: It sounds like you're more concerned with whether the data still exists, in which case you'd be better keeping track of a boolean called dataIsValid or something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you've actually set the pointer to null after deleting it, there's no real way to determine whether that slot in the vector contains a pointer to a live object or not.

So you'd need to:
`delete vec[5];
vec[5] = NULL;`

Then you could test

`if (vec[5] == NULL)`

to determine if there was "really" something at that location or not.

Answer (score 3):

There is no code for that, not without extra careful work in your deleting process.  If you store smart pointers you can do it like this:

```
vector<unique_ptr<x>> var;
// assuming you actually do add 6 or more elements to the vector
...
var[5].reset();

if (var[5]) { ... }
```

Comment: If you insist on storing pointers, smart pointers are the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `var.size()` to see if the vector contains a pointer at `var[5]`, but that won't tell you whether the pointer is valid.

You could create a small wrapper class:

```
template <class T>
class wrapper {
    bool valid;
    T *data_;
public:
    wrapper(T *d): data_(d), valid(true) {}
    del() { delete data; valid = false; }
    bool isValid() { return valid; }
    T *data() { return valid ? data : NULL; }
};

std::vector<wrapper<x> > var;

var[5].del();

if (var[5].valid())
   var[5].data()->Pos_X = 20;
```

Personally, I'd prefer to just ensure that all the pointers are valid all the time though.

Comment: @TiagoSalzmann: For a sufficiently narrow definition of "works". If, for example, you copy one of these and use `del()` in one copy, the other won't know the data has been deleted. I've also just edited the code a bit to fix a couple of minor errors (but it's still not tested, much less proved, so a few more bugs are likely.

Answer (score 0):

calling delete you are deallocating memory pointed by that x*, so you still have pointer to some memory address that do not contain anymore what you excpected.

If you want to remove elements from vector consider using "erase"; then, if you don't want to erase but simply "cancel" the Nth element, structure is yours.. put some bool flag inside your structure.

Comment: OK, can you give me an example?

Comment: If you want to keep your vector space allocated (so not erasing items) add to your structure a bool valid; field then when you want to delete it (actually "invalidate"):  var[5].valid = false; and when you want to validate again set it to true. If you don't need to actually free memory it's a light solution; then you can incapsulate this logic inside some method or wrapper similarly to what @Jerry Coffin said